# A problem of urns.

Tags: probability

Suppose there are $N$ balls of different colors and $K$ urns. 
For each ball $i=1,...,N$ it is extracted a 
flat integer random number $k_i$ between $1$ and $K$ and the ball $i$ is randomly assigned to $k_i$ urns (so the same color may appears in more than one urn). Let $C_{i,k}$ be the matrix defined as

$$
C_{i,k}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 
1 & \textrm{ if ball }i\textrm{ is in urn }k\\
0 & \textrm{ otherwise }.
\end{array}\right.
$$

Given two urns $k$ and $q$ I need to know the distribution of the co-occurrences

$$
J_{k,q} = \sum_{i=1}^{N}C_{i,k}\,C_{i,q},
$$

that is the number of balls of the same color they have in common. Note that the hypergeometric distribution would be obtained once the occupancy numbers

$$
u_{k} = \sum_{i=1}^{N}C_{i,k}
$$

were given as fixed quantities. Unfortunately this is not the case and I am stuck with this problem. 
It would be enough to compute the expected value $\mathbb{E}\left[J_{k,q}\right]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of $K$, $k_i$ and $k$ is slightly confusing.

$\Pr(k_i=m) = \frac{1}{K}$ for $m$ in $1,2,\ldots,K$; given $m$, the probability that ball $i$ is in both of urns $k$ and $q$ is $\frac{m(m-1)}{K(K-1)}$.  So overall the probability ball $i$ is in both of urns $k$ and $q$ is $\sum_m \frac1K\frac{m(m-1)}{K(K-1)} = \frac{K+1}{3K}$.

Expectation is linear and there are $N$ balls so  $\displaystyle \mathbb{E}\left[J_{k,q}\right] = \frac{N(K+1)}{3K}$ if $k \not = q$.

Similarly $\displaystyle \mathbb{E}\left[J_{k,k}\right] = \frac{N(K+1)}{2K}$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. With $k$ I mean just an index that runs from $1$ to $K$(as it does $q$). The capital letter $K$ is the total number of urns while $k_i$ is the number of urns in which ball $i$ is placed.

Comment: If the urns are different then each $J_{k,q}$ has a binomial distribution $\text{Bin}\left(n,\frac{K+1}{3K}\right)$, but they are not independent.